# Give a pseudocode for an algorithm that, given a list of n integers from the set {0, 1,

Tags: sorting, big-o, computer-science, counting-sort

Problem statement:

> Give a pseudocode for an algorithm that, given a list of n integers from the set {0, 1, . . . , k−1},
>   preprocesses its input to extract and store information that makes it possible to answer any query asking
>   how many of the n integers fall in the range [a..b] (with a and b being input parameters to the query) in
>   O(1) time. Explain how your algorithm works.
>   The preprocessing time should be O(n + k) in the worst case. Provide an argument showing that your
>   preprocessing algorithm meets that bound.

My attempt:

```
Counting Sort Pseudo Code
function countingSort(array, min, max)
  count: array of (max – min + 1) elements //max is highest number, min is lowest 
  initialize count with 0 //set count = 0
  for each number in array do
    count[number – min] := count[number-min] + 1 //element i – min element = pos. 
                                                 //pos + 1
  done
  z:= 0
  for i from min to max do
    while(count[ i – min] >0) do
      array[z] := i
      z := z + 1
      count[i – min] := count [i – min] – 1
    done
   done

Find Pseudo Code
find(a, b)
  ??
```

Time Complexity Analysis:
We find that the total time complexity of Counting Sort takes O(k) time to initialize the array, O(n) time to read in the numbers and increment the appropriate element of counts. Another O(k) to create the array z, and another O(n) to scan and read through the list of numbers for a toal runtime of O(n+k).

Question:
The only problem I am having is that I do not know how I will report back to the user the number of integers that lie in between the range they have chosen [a..b] in O(1) time.. The only way I can think of retrieving that information is by looping through my array of sorted integers and having a counter to increment each time we find a number such that some some **element** is >= a && some **element** is <= b. Also should I include the actual numbers they have inputted in my search or rather should I just count the numbers in between them? The problem with looping through the array and having a counter to count the numbers between [a..b] is that this requires a **for** loop and is O(n). Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Sorry, i'll remove the tag.

Comment: It's ok, I've removed it already

Comment: So you've figured out everything except what the problem wants you to figure out?

Comment: No, I've figured out everything except the last part of the problem. Read the OP.

Comment: Use a cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was trivial, just didn't think about it. After I use counting sort it resorts my list so that all I have to do is take the difference of the range asked of from the user. So for example

```
find(a,b)
  numberofIntegersBetweenAandB = count[b] - count[a]
```

Comment: Using count[b] - count[a] won't work unless count is converted into a series of cumulative sums as commented by Nayuki Minase.

Comment: Counting Sort sorts the array such that using the difference of the final array will give you the amount of integers between the ranges a and b that you have queried. That's how it works.

Comment: The example code shown in the question only generates an array of counts of instances: count[i] = # instances of min + i. A counting sort will then loop on the count array a second time, converting it into a cumulative sum of instances, but that is not shown in the pseudo code posted. Also there needs to a minor correction, how many integers are there between [a,a], which should be the number of instances of a, but count[a] - count[a] == 0. The problem statement uses [a,b], which is a closed interval that includes both a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Working C++ example. Since the goal here is psuedo code, there are no error checks.

```
int * GenerateSums(int a[], size_t n, int min, int max)
{
    size_t k = max + 2 - min;
    int *sums = new int[k];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < k; i++)   // clear sums
        sums[i] = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)   // set number of instances
        sums[1+a[i]-min]++;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < k; i++)   // convert to cumulative sums
        sums[i] += sums[i-1];
    return sums;
}

int CountInRange(int sums[], int a, int b)
{
    return sums[b+1] - sums[a];
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {4,0,3,4,2,4,1,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,3,1};
    int *sums = GenerateSums(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), 0, 4);
    int cnt;
    cnt = CountInRange(sums, 0, 0);  // returns  1
    cnt = CountInRange(sums, 3, 4);  // returns 10
    cnt = CountInRange(sums, 0, 4);  // returns 16
    delete[] sums;
    return 0;
}
```